# Lamp на Ubuntu

Tags: lamp, ubuntu

Первый день работаю с Lubuntu, подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно разместить Lamp на свою новую мало изведанную (ос). Заранее спасибо за ваши ответы и коментарии.

(alt+ctrl+T)

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get install apache2 php5 mysql
```

Или так или почти так. 
Когда этим занимался - никаких проблем не возникло.

P.S.: lxde - респект!

Comment: через sudo вводить установщик?

Answer (score 0):

Через synaptic. Там в 1 клик lamp можно поставить. Только вот мне phpmyadmin пришлось допиливать.

Comment: на форуме lubuntu советую установить 'xammp' может кто то юзал ?